# Two join statements gives Unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have this SQL query :

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `ves_brand` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT value from catalog_product_entity_int 
    where row_id in 
        (select row_id from catalog_product_entity_int 
        WHERE (attribute_id, value) IN ( (99, 4) ))) AS `t` 
ON main_table.brand_id = t.value 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cpeiz` 
ON cpeiz.row_id = catalog_product_entity_int.row_id 
WHERE (cpeiz.attribute_set_id != 19)
```

This gives the error:
`#1054 - Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity_int.row_id' in 'on clause'`

Even if I set an alias for the column `catalog_product_entity_int.row_id`, the column is always "unknown".

Comment: Is row_id a column the catalog_product_entity_int table

Comment: I don't follow what you want to do at all.  Sample data and a desired result would really help, as would an explanation of the logic you want to accomplish.

Comment: personal advice: try to format your SQL-statements
have a look at http://www.sqlstyle.guide/
proper formated SQL statements are make trouble shooting & all futher changes easier for you and your fellows

Comment: Won't your subquery just select value `4`? Why so difficult?

Comment: `t.value` instead of  `catalog_product_entity_int.row_id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catalog_product_entity_int` is defined inside your subquery, you can't reference it directly from outside your subquery.  (think of it like a local variable, you have to pass it back somehow to the main query)

Very dependent on your dataset, but something like this will work

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `ves_brand` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT value, row_id from catalog_product_entity_int 
    where row_id in 
        (select row_id from catalog_product_entity_int 
        WHERE (attribute_id, value) IN ( (99, 4) ))) AS `t` 
ON main_table.brand_id = t.value 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cpeiz` 
ON cpeiz.row_id = t.row_id 
WHERE (cpeiz.attribute_set_id != 19)
```

Comment: Be aware that this now changes the SELECT DISTINCT to be distinct COMBINATIONS of VALUE and ROW_ID .. this might not be what you want.

Comment: I added a `group by brand_id`.